# Can you set up Git source code control with a ring-topology?

Tags: git, topology

I was wondering if anyone has ever set up a Git source control system with a ring topology (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_topology). I think this should work, but I was wondering if anyone has verified it.

Say I have a small company with 4 remote developers: Alex, Bob, Carrie, and Dan

Assume that each member of the team has a Git repository which we will be setup as

- Alex repository with origin set to
  Bob
- Bob repository with origin set to
  Carrie
- Carrie repository with origin set to
  Dan
- Dan repository with origin set to Alex

Since all commits are tracked by SHA1 hash, it seems that there should be no issues when things come back round the ring.

Just wondering if anyone has tested or experience with this type of setup?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but that (ring) is more suited for environment workflow.
For instance, one could imagine (not an ideal workflow, but for this example it will do):

- **Dev** pushes to Tests (could pull some bugfixes if made in Tests)
- **Tests** pushes to Pre-Prod (should not pull from prod)
- **Pre-prod** pushed to Prod (should not pull from prod)
- **Prod** pushes some hotfixes to Dev (but never pull directly from dev)

Amongst developer, the topology is much more loose (not necessarily a ring, but more of an ad-hoc network depending on the collaboration level needed).